# making a function staticmethod in python is confusing

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, pycharm

Hi I have a GUI written using Tkinter and the code template is as follows. My question is PyCharm gives me warnings on my functions (def func1, def func2) that they are static. To get rid of the warnings I placed @staticmethod above the functions. What does this do and is it necessary?

```
# Use TKinter for python 2, tkinter for python 3
import Tkinter as Tk
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import os, fnmatch
import tkFont


class MainWindow(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('BandCad')
        self.initialize()

    @staticmethod
    def si_units(self, string):

        if string.endswith('M'):
            num = float(string.replace('M', 'e6'))
        elif string.endswith('K'):
            num = float(string.replace('K', 'e3'))
        elif string.endswith('k'):
            num = float(string.replace('k', 'e3'))
        else:
            num = float(string)
        return num



if __name__ == "__main__":
#    main()
    root = Tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: PyCharm gives you that warning if your method doesn't actually refer to `self`. `@staticmethod` just means a method that doesn't get passed the instance, conventionally named `self`. From the code you've posted, it's hard to add anything else.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Thanks for your comment. I edited my code. Does this help give you more info to answer.

Comment: More info isn't *needed*; that's all it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also turn off that inspection so that PyCharm doesn't warn you. Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections. Note that the inspection appears in the JavaScript section as well as the Python section.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about @staticmethod being confusing.  It is not really needed in Python code and in my opinion should almost never by used.  Instead, since si_units is not a method, move it out of the class and remove the unused self parameter.  (Actually, you should have done that when adding @staticmethod; the posted code will not work right with 'self' left in.)

Unless one has forgotten to use 'self' when it needs to be used, this is (or at least should be) the intent of the PyCharm warning.  No confusion, no fiddling with PyCharm settings.

While you are at it, you could condense the function and make it easily extensible to other suffixes by using a dict.

```
def si_units(string):
    d = {'k':'e3', 'K':'e3', 'M':'e6'}
    end = string[-1]
    if end in d:
        string = string[:-1] + d[end]
    return float(string)

for f in ('1.5', '1.5k', '1.5K', '1.5M'): print(si_units(f))
```